# Flutter: Can I Disable GoogleMap Camera Move?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

So I have a form like below

[image]

I want to disable camera movement when user dragging in google map form. Is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some parameters for `GoogleMap` that handle the user interactions

```dart
                zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
                scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
                tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
                zoomControlsEnabled: false,
```